bootstrap datepicker not showing date dropbox
I have the following script that works fine:
<head>
    <title>DateTimepicker</title>
 
    <!-- Include Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link href=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js">
    </script>
    <script src=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
 
    <!-- Include Moment.js CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js">
    </script>
 
    <!-- Include Bootstrap DateTimePicker CDN -->
    <link
        href=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
 
    <script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
        </script>
</head>
 
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h3>Bootstrap 4 and Tempus Dominus in a modal</h3>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Click to open Modal</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Date and time</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
  });
});
</script>

Then i use it to create form on dynamic action modal, it's fail.
Here my code to get action modal
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){   
       $('#menu-load').html('C:/xampp/htdocs/menu.html');
    });
});
</script>

My menu.html
 <div class="card card-style">
        <div class="content mb-2">
         <div class="input-style has-icon input-style-1 input-required">
        <i class="input-icon fas fa-calendar-times"></i>
        <span>Start</span>
        <em>(required)</em>
                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
         </div>   
            
            <button type="button" class="submitform btn  btn-lg btn-block btn-full btn-m shadow-l rounded-s text-uppercase font-900 bg-green1-dark" data-id = "add">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>

Action modal generate from server by load another html.
This is my datepicker on my action modal (https://i.sstatic.net/CU4KvWSr.png)
Look like dropdown datepicker generate, but not show anything...
i try to change code to
<script>
    $("#menu-load").on("click","#datetimepicker1",function(t){
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
      });
    });
</script>

